# Java Unicode problem

Tags: database, unicode, jakarta-ee

My question would be what's wrong with the next code? I'm trying with j2ee to read some unicode from a database and some characters are returned as the famous question mark.

try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hortimart?" +
                                   "user=webservices&password=stipjeservers";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

```
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String SQL = "SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM users";

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next())
        {

            byte[] firstNameBytes = rs.getBytes(1);
            String FirstName =new String(firstNameBytes,"UTF-8");
            byte [] lastNameBytes = rs.getBytes(2);
            String LastName =new String(lastNameBytes,"UTF-8");
            System.out.println(FirstName+" "+LastName);

        }

    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cE)
    {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
    }
```

Now i've tried this code with j2Se as well and it works. So is it j2EE or i missed something in my code?

Thanks

Comment: i'm usign NetBeans with an integrated Tomcat6.0 server. For my DB i'm using EasyPHP 3.0. maybe this helps

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely your **console** that's misconfigured. Have you examined the bytes of the result to see if it's UTF-8?

Comment: i'm not getting UTF-8. all i get are numbers like this -72 -48 -67 -48 -77 -48 which appear to be correct since i get the same numbers in j2me as in j2se and in j2se the characters are displayed correctly

Comment: If they are the same numbers in two places, and those numbers display as expected in one place, then it is the **display** that is broken, as I suggested, and not the encoding. UTF-8 **is** a series of "numbers", which have to be decoded and interpreted as Unicode code points to be displayed as human-readable glyphs.

Comment: i'm using NetBeans and the only difference between those two places is  this: in a simple java project it works (j2se) but in a web project it doesn't (j2ee).

Comment: the display is the NetBeans console and it's the same for both projects

Comment: Your problems are: not understanding what Unicode is, what UTF-8 is, how System.out works, and how to recognize the right answer when it's staring you in the face. Good luck!

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: +1 since it encapsulates everything I thought but couldn't face writing out. I'd give it another +1 for the Joel article if I could...

Answer (score 0):

try to append characterEncoding=utf-8 to your connection url.
ie:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hortimart?" + "user=webservices&password=stipjeservers&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Comment: unfortunately the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Do you *know* if the strings have been encoded in UTF-8 (Unicode encompasses many encodings, UTF-8 being only one of them). Have you tried using a simple `rs.getString(1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that either i) you have data in the database that is not unicode (how are your tables defined?) or ii) that your driver is not unicode-enabled.

**EDIT**: Have you tried setting both useUnicode and characterEncoding in your connection string?

```
...useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Comment: the type of the fields is varchar and the Collation is set to utf8_unicode_ci(unicode multilangual, case insensitive)

Comment: useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 
this doesn't work either